# Redirect main url to /?lang=ur in laravel site with .htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I have script of laravel, It have 2 languages English and Urdu, By default it opens `example.com` with English language but when I click on language selector so it redirect site to
`example.com/?lang=ur` But I want to open `/?lang=ur` by default with `.htaccess`.

In `.htaccess` it have code like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

in public folder htaccess it have code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When i open my site so it open by default english site without any language parameter in url, after changing language first time it have language parameter but when i open inner pages so it remove language parameter but keep rtl formating.

Please tell me how can I redirect `https://example.com` to `https://example.com/?lang=ur`

Comment: "in htaccess it have code like" - That can't be the only code you have. You presumably have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory that has all the "important stuff"? Do you literally only want to redirect the "homepage", as in your example? Inner URLs should not be redirected?

Comment: When you use the "language selector" to pick _English_, what is the resulting URL? Does it simply remove the `lang` URL parameter? Or does it use `lang=en` or similar?

Comment: when i select urdu or enlgish then first time it will have /lang=ur or en , but when i will open inner pages it do not have /lang=ur or en in urls but keep rtl or ltr format. and yes you are right, public directory also have htaccess code

Comment: "but when i will open inner pages it do not have /lang=ur or en in URLs" - I think you should be defaulting the language in your Laravel application, not `.htaccess`. The "problem" with doing this in `.htaccess` is that it would seem you can't simply look at the URL to determine whether a language has been selected by the user or not, since this is not necessarily present in the URL. It's possibly being passed in a _cookie_ (or _session variable_) on subsequent requests. If it is using a cookie, then what cookie? If it's using the session then you _cannot_ do this using `.htaccess`.

Comment: In other words... when a user visits `example.com/`, how do you determine whether a user  is visiting the site for the first time and not yet selected a language OR has recently  selected "English" and is simply navigating back to the homepage (ie. `example.com/`)?